# Python3: copy/paste sequence works only if done in two steps

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

I have the same problem on Cygwin/Windows and into a Debian ditro via ssh. If I open a terminal, and copy/paste this whole code at once:

```
f = open('dst.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
f.write('\xc4\xc4\xc4')
f.close
text = open('dst.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
text
len(text)
```

I get:

```
Python 3.6.0a0 (default, Jul  7 2015, 23:55:18)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('dst.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
>>> f.write('\xc4\xc4\xc4')
3
>>> f.close
<built-in method close of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x7f65c03b8b40>
>>> text = open('dst.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
>>> text
''
>>> len(text)
0
>>>
```

Now if I do it in **two** steps:

```
f = open('dst.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
f.write('\xc4\xc4\xc4')
f.close
```

Then:

```
text = open('dst.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
text
len(text)
```

I get:

```
xx@xx:~$ python3
Python 3.6.0a0 (default, Jul  7 2015, 23:55:18)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('dst.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
>>> f.write('\xc4\xc4\xc4')
3
>>> f.close
<built-in method close of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x7fb1a9353b40>
>>>
xx@xx:~$ python3
Python 3.6.0a0 (default, Jul  7 2015, 23:55:18)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> text = open('dst.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
>>> text
'ÄÄÄ'
>>> len(text)
3
>>>
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't called the close method, you've just referenced it - note that the shell prints what the method is, rather than its result (which would be None). So the file is still open for writing when you attempt to read it. Obviously, when you quit the interpreter, the file is closed.

The third line should be:

```
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually call the method, so the contents didn't have a chance to become readable yet.

```
f.close()
```